# elastic-builder: how to combine boolquery with rangequery in one query?

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

Basically, I have a request to search for documents with specific tag(s) attached in create range between given startDate and endDate. I use below code for query

```
createBoolQuery(): Query {
    return (
      esb
        .boolQuery()
        .filter(esb.termsQuery("tags", ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]))
    );
  }
createRangeQuery(): Query {
      const query = esb.rangeQuery("createdDate");
      if (this._rangeStartDate) {
        const startDate = moment(this._rangeStartDate);
        query.gte(startDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
      }
      if (this._rangeEndDate) {
        const endDate = moment(this._rangeEndDate);
        query.lte(endDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
      }

      return query;
  }
const query
```

const searchQuery = esb.RequestBodySearch().query(this.createBoolQuery()).query(this.createRangeQuery())

**searchQuery** in above code is

> query: {range: {createdDate: {gte: "09/29/2021", lte: "11/03/2021"}}}

which you can see boolQuery part is missing, however if I replace code to use boolquery only, like

```
const searchQuery = esb.RequestBodySearch().query(this.createBoolQuery())
```

then the **searchQuery** is

> query: {filter: {terms: {tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}}}}

Need big help to use just one query including both boolQuery and rangeQuery.